# Automatically Scale Vimeo Video to 100% of Page Height

Tags: javascript, video

Hi There: Are any of you aware of a method for taking the vimeo embed code and making it scale to 100% of a page? Here is an example of what I'm looking to do.

http://player.vimeo.com/video/4643702

Please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Here is the embed code that vimeo produces by default: <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/28078920?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=F15724" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: Add a `height="100%"` to the iframe.

Comment: Won't that kill the aspect ratio of the video?

Answer (score 0):

Setting width="100%" will set your  height to something smaller that you want in most cases. And setting height="100%" will not preserve your aspect ratio.

What I suggest you do:

1. set position of  to fixed or absolute (see what suites you the most)
2. set width and height of  to the same as video file is
3. use JS or jQuery on document.ready to set aspect ratio for  using
   his attributes width and height
4. set it's width to 100% of the screen
5. set it's height to **width** that multiplies **aspect ratio** from above
6. handel window.resize event, because maybe in some cases width will be smallet than height so you must set  height to 100% and recalculate the width